# Nuxt3 and Vuetify3 - get initial state of useDisplay() props if SSR is enabled

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

The project uses Nuxt3 and Vuetify3 stack.
I've started to work on an adaptive mobile layout.

To manage different layout I use `useDisplay()` as per [official docs](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/display-and-platform/).

It works fine if SSR is disabled. But if it's enabled, it'll always return the initial value of params because the server didn't know anything about the client.

```js
export const vuetify = createVuetify({
  ssr: true
})
```

What is the best way to handle that?

[Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: CSS is not enough for your use case? Otherwise, you probably need to install it for client-only. What [you did](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#ssr) is great so far. Now use `useDisplay()` (if really needed) only on client side hooks.

Comment: I prefer to use native tools instead of custom css. That why I try to find the most widely used solution for such a regular use case.

Comment: CSS will always be better than JS for styling. Also, Vuetify is not "native" to the platform, CSS is baked-in into all browsers.

Comment: @kissu thanks for the reply. Will use media or will create isMobile prop if won’t find a smarter solution

Answer (score 0):

You can [Vuetify Nuxt Module](https://github.com/userquin/vuetify-nuxt-module) to handle the viewport in SSR.

Docs related: https://vuetify-nuxt-module.netlify.app/guide/server-side-rendering.html#vuetify-display